# Radio button toggle expand using Bootstrap 4

Tags: toggle, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap 4 to create a form that expands different elements as each "button" is clicked.

How it should work:
Buttons(radio): YES / NO ---
If "YES" is clicked then it expands an element containing checkbox buttons.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false"> 
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Yes
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> No
  </label>
</div>
<!-- Expanded Buttons -->
<div class="btn-group collapse" id="collapseExample" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
<!-- / Expand Buttons -->
```

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/CaitlynF/pen/KZJWYd) to my Pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do it using only native Bootstrap 4 classes (without any custom css), then this would be one way of doing it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler pl-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false"> 
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
    </button>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> No
    </label>

    <div class="collapse pl-4" id="collapseExample">
        <!-- Expanded Buttons -->
        <div class="btn-group collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
            </label>
        </div>
        <!-- / Expand Buttons -->
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Just did a minor update to my snippet. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works and I have used the CSS 
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
to remove the default boxes. But the checkboxes aren't changing colour when checked anymore. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution, that shows the div when Yes is checked, and hides it if No is checked:

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample:not(.show)"> Yes
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample.show"> No
</label>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    Gets toggled by radios
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/145741/)